# c - data type if statement not recognizing numerical values

Tags: c, types

I am trying to take in 10 characters over a serial console and add them to an array called `buffer`. The characters need to be one of the following 0,1,L or S.

It says that 1 and 0 are invalid but 'L' and 'S' are ok. Have I got my data types wrong?

Thanks

```
int main(void)
{
int ch;

char buffer[10] = "";

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

    putstring("Enter command\r\n");
    ch = getcharacter();

    if ((ch == '0') || (ch == '1') || (ch == 'L') || (ch == 'S')) {

        buffer[i] = ch;
        putstring(ch);
    }
    else {
        putstring("Input not valid");
        break;
    }
}
}


void putstring(char *str) {

    /*Needs an error check such as timeout or check for NULL string*/
    const uint32_t transmit_ready = 1 << 6;

    while (*str != '\0') {

        if ((*uart_status_reg)  & transmit_ready) {

            *uart_txdata_reg = *str;
            str++;
        }
    }

}

int getcharacter(void) {

    uint8_t c = 0;
    const uint32_t recieve_ready = 1 << 7;

    //disable interrupt for a read ready
    *uart_control_reg = 0;

    while (1) {
        //check if RRDY bit is set
        if ((*uart_status_reg) & recieve_ready) {
            c = *uart_rxdata_reg;
            break;
        }
    }
    return ((int) c);
}
```

Comment: Why don;t you add some debugging after the return of `getcharacter()`?

Comment: `putstring(ch);` is wrong as it expects a string but you give it an int. Turn warnings on; your compiler should have flagged this. The receive code looks OK, except possibly the return of int instead of unsigned int.

Comment: Note that `buffer` should be size 11 to be able to hold 10 characters _and a terminating null_. You are lucky that you initialized buffer to "" as now it is all zeroes, because you forget to add the terminating null (or was that intentional?)

Comment: If the program rejects input you think it should accept, then one of the first things you should be checking is whether it is actually receiving what you think it is receiving.  Or to put it another way, if control reaches `putstring("Input not valid");` then it follows that `ch` is not equal to any of `'0'`, `'1'`, `'L'`, or `'S'`.  Perhaps you have a case-sensitivity issue?

Comment: Or scratch the case-sensitivity -- I see that you said it is the 'L' and 'S' that you receive correctly, not the other way around.  Consider, then, whether you are receiving the bytes with *values* 0 and 1, as opposed to the bytes that represent the *digit characters* '0' and '1'.

Comment: `int ch; ... putstring(ch);` and `putstring(char *str)` is calling a `char *` function with an `int`.

Comment: the posted code does not compile! it is missing the required `#include` statements.  Do you expect us to guess as to which header files your code actually included?

Comment: the posted code is missing the `prototypes` for the sub functions: `getcharacter()`, `putstring()`,

Comment: this statement: `putstring(ch);` will not work correctly.  The function: `putstring()` is expecting a pointer to a char array that is NUL byte terminated but variable `ch` is an integer, not a NUL terminated character array

Comment: the function: `getcharacter()` disables the interrupt, but never re-enables that interrupt and there is no code to handle an interrupt from that source.

Comment: the global array `buffer[10]` is being set, but never used.

Comment: in function: `main()` the variable 'ch' is declared as an `int`.  but none of the code requires it to be anything but a `char`  So why is it declared as an `int`

Comment: what happens if the incoming char is `l` or `s` (I.E. lower case)?